# Inconsistency in form validity when adding/removing elements from array

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

See this Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/rnydqGw9nxbR61Dut4yS?p=preview

I have a template like so:

```
<form #editorForm="ngForm">
    <button (click)="addField()">add</button>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let field of fields; let index=index">
        <input type="text" required name="field-{{index}}" [(ngModel)]="field.label">
        <button (click)="deleteField(index)">delete</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    valid: <span [style.color]="editorForm.valid ? 'green' : 'red'">{{editorForm.valid}}</span>
</form>
```

And a controller like so:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public fields: Field[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fields = [];
  }

    public addField(): void {
        this.fields.push({
            label: "",
        });
    }

    public deleteField(index: number) {
        this.fields.splice(index, 1);
    }
}

export class Field {
    public label: string;
}
```

If you add two fields, you can see that the form is now invalid (as expected), and then remove in order, the bottom field and THEN the top field, the form is now valid (as expected).

But if I add two fields, and then remove the top one first and THEN the bottom field, the form continues to be invalid. The form *should* become valid again.

Another thing you can try is add 3 fields, then remove from top to bottom (it's now invalid). Then add 2 fields, and remove bottom to top. Normally, bottom to top removal would work, but since we added 3 prior, you now need to add 3 and then remove them bottom to top to fix the problem. So it appears there is some sort of Angular state sticking around somehow... Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are adding and removing DOM elements *`ngFor` needs `trackBy` attribute so the form can follow elements validity changes:

**TypeScript:**

```
trackBy(index, item) {
   return index;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<li *ngFor="let field of fields; trackBy:trackBy; let index=index">
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uoazgv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

You can read more on this [here](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5)

Comment: @Chris Smith, was this what you where looking for?

Comment: Oh, great! glad to help